# How to use a graphic for labeling in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, labeling

The "label" option in QGIS allows a wide range of possibilities for displaying attributes of an object in the map.

Is there a way to use a symbol/graphic (eg stopsign.png) for labeling objects of a (polygon) layer?

Comment: Interesting although that's probably more suitable for styling rather than labeling.

Comment: Why do you want to use labeling rather than styling to place eg a stop sign?

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was possible in the styling section, I'll have a look at this, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If 'Scaleable Vector Graphics' (.SVG) symbol is also an option, then yes you can use it for labeling objects (polygon in your case).
Right click on the layer and navigate to Properties > Labels > Background. From the Shape dropdown select SVG and browse for the appropriate symbol as shown in the screen shot.

As a result it will draw graphic symbols in the centroid of each polygon.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, excuse my blindness and thank you